# Return single entity selected by ID from a Service using Repository pattern

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, repository-pattern

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC3 application. I want to make a method in my service that will return only the entity with the id that I provide from the place I call the method.

In my service which is called `DocumentService` I wrote the following simple method:

```
public Documents GetDocById(long id)
{
    return DocumentsRepository.All().Where(d => d.Id == id);
}
```

Because I want only a single entity i decided that I should set the return type of the method to the type of the entity which is called `Documents`. The error I get with this code is :

`Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Linq.IQueryable<DataAccess.Documents> to DataAccess.Documents.`

And that's logical. But thinking what should I do to transform it to the type I want I find myself in question. For example I could make the return type of the method `List<Documents>` and then add `ToList()` at the end of my return statement. But I'm not expecting a List, I'm expecting a single record and not List of records.

So is there a way and if there is, how can I return only one entity instead of List with one item which is what I can think of now?

Answer (score 2):

```
return DocumentsRepository.All().SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
```

or

```
return DocumentsRepository.All().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
```

if there are multiple entities with the same id.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen thanks but afaik it is supported with .net 4?

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
public Documents GetDocById(long id)
{
    return DocumentsRepository.All().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
return DocumentsRepository.All().Where(d => d.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return `null` if there is no document with the given `Id`.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgotten about that. I'm gonna use it!